# How to run a java program from another java program?

Tags: java

So I have a java program of a game. I want to have a different program and when you click on a button there that java program closes and starts the program with the game. But I have no idea how I can do that, so can anyone help me?

Comment: did you google before ask?

Comment: Are you sure you want to start a new program or do you maybe just want to open another frame showing your program?

Comment: Well I don't know whats easier, but I don't have a lot of Java knowledge.

Comment: It is way easier staying in your own program and just show another JFrame (assuming you coded that in swing) from your main method which then will open your game JFrame once the user click's that button.

Answer (score 1):

Using ProcessBuilder.The following is a reference,maybe not work.

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar","Test3.jar");
pb.directory(new File("F:\\dist"));
Map<String,String> map=pb.environment();
Process p=pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a runnable jar.
2. call the runnable jar on button click.
3. Exit from the current program.